# too few arguments in ImageCmsElementResolver error after update from 6.4.8.2 to 6.4.13.0

Tags: php, updates, shopware, shopware6, swupdate

got the following error after updating from sw 6.4.8.2 to 6.4.13.0
how to solve this?

```
In ImageCmsElementResolver.php line 26:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  [ArgumentCountError]                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  Too few arguments to function Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Cms\ImageCmsElementResolver::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/xxxx/yyyyy/var/cache/dev_h444cf98b71a1ac0a254d0a81916b032e/ContainerG5HDhmp/Shopware_Production_Kernel  
  DevDebugContainer.php on line 6664 and exactly 1 expected
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Did you check Shopware's upgrade notes for hints about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `parent="Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Cms\ImageCmsElementResolver"` to your service-registration in services.xml.

f.e.

```
<service id="My\Plugin\Core\Content\Media\Cms\Type\Teaser5in1TypeDataResolver"
                 parent="Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Cms\ImageCmsElementResolver">
            <tag name="shopware.cms.data_resolver"/>
        </service>
```

Read more: https://github.com/shopware/platform/issues/2463

Comment: i searched all plugins therefore and changed what i could find. it did not fix the problem. i deactivated the theme i suspected via the database. after that i could update the theme and now it works. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was also the Theme incompatibility — deactivating it and reinstalling the update ([as explained here](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/update-guides/updating-shopware)) solved the issue.